# Change attributes via script for Camera/Imageplane

Tags: maya, autodesk, mel

ok so currently i have this

```
string $cam[] = `ls -sl`;
string $camR[] = listRelatives($cam[0]);
string $camC[] = listConnections($camR[0]);

if (getAttr($camC[0]+".depth" == 2)){
    setAttr $camC[0]+".depth" = 10000;
    setAttr $camC[0]+".alpha" = 0.5;
    setAttr $camR[0]+".nearClipPlane" = 1;
};
```

which should give you a rough idea of what im trying to do.
it needs to be dynamic so it works with any camera, any name and multiple connections/relations attached to that camera. Basically, if it's a camera that has an imagePlane attached, this script must edit all attributes.

Any suggestions?

Note: using maya2020 so some functions might be different from 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning attributes work a little bit differently in mel.
This should work:

```
string $cameras[] = `ls -sl`;
string $shapes[] = `listRelatives -s $cameras[0]`;

for( $shape in $shapes)
{
    string $imagePlaneShapes[] = `listConnections -sh 1 $shape`;
    if(`getAttr ($imagePlaneShapes[0] + ".depth")` == 2)
    {     
        setAttr ($imagePlaneShapes[0]+".depth") 10000;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the c[0] for? did you mean cameras[0]?

Comment: either with $c[0] and $cameras[0] it gives me a syntax error and empty list. Maybe this syntax doesn't work in maya 2020

Comment: Sorry my fault. The `ls -sl -t camera` only works if a camera shape is selected and indeed the $c should be $camera. I corrected syntax, should work better now.